# how to use aa_chart_view kotlin(getting runtime error)

Tags: android, kotlin, plot

I'm trying to plot some data using [aa_chart_view](https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartCore-Kotlin) library and I followed the instruction up until the point of binding activity_main.xml component to the code, the doc suggests using kotlin-android-extensions which is deprecated and the error suggests using kotlin-parcelize which I did and now I've got the following code:

```
package no.nordicsemi.android.uart.view

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Delete
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.github.aachartmodel.aainfographics.aachartcreator.AAChartModel
import com.github.aachartmodel.aainfographics.aachartcreator.AAChartType
import com.github.aachartmodel.aainfographics.aachartcreator.AAChartView
import com.github.aachartmodel.aainfographics.aachartcreator.AASeriesElement
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import no.nordicsemi.android.theme.view.SectionTitle
import no.nordicsemi.android.uart.R
import no.nordicsemi.android.uart.data.UARTRecord
import no.nordicsemi.android.uart.data.UARTRecordType
import no.nordicsemi.android.uart.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

@Override
fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

@Composable
internal fun OutputSection(records: List<UARTRecord>, onEvent: (UARTViewEvent) -> Unit) {
//    val aaChartView = findViewById<AAChartView>(R.id.aa_chart_view)
    val aaChartModel : AAChartModel = AAChartModel()
        .chartType(AAChartType.Area)
        .title("title")
        .subtitle("subtitle")
        .backgroundColor("#4b2b7f")
        .dataLabelsEnabled(true)
        .series(arrayOf(
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Tokyo")
                .data(arrayOf(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("NewYork")
                .data(arrayOf(0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5)),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("London")
                .data(arrayOf(0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0)),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Berlin")
                .data(arrayOf(3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8))
        )
        )
    binding.aaChartView.aa_drawChartWithChartModel(aaChartModel)
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))

        val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
        val scrollDown = remember {
            derivedStateOf { scrollState.isScrolledToTheEnd() }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            state = scrollState
        ) {
            if (records.isEmpty()) {
                item { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.uart_output_placeholder)) }
            } else {
                records.forEach {
                    item {
                        when (it.type) {
                            UARTRecordType.INPUT -> MessageItemInput(record = it)
                            UARTRecordType.OUTPUT -> MessageItemOutput(record = it)
                        }

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        LaunchedEffect(records, scrollDown.value) {
            if (!scrollDown.value || records.isEmpty()) {
                return@LaunchedEffect
            }
            launch {
                scrollState.scrollToItem(records.lastIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}


fun LazyListState.isScrolledToTheEnd() = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1

@Composable
private fun MessageItemInput(record: UARTRecord) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {
        Text(
            text = record.timeToString(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp, bottomStart = 10.dp))
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary)
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "ksndfkjsndkjs",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MessageItemOutput(record: UARTRecord) {
//    Column(
//        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
//        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
//    ) {
//        Text(
//            text = record.timeToString(),
//            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
//            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
//        )
//        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
//        Column(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp, bottomEnd = 10.dp))
//                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
//                .padding(8.dp)
//        ) {
//            Text(
//                text = record.text,
//                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
//                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
//            )
//        }
//    }
}

@Composable
private fun Menu(onEvent: (UARTViewEvent) -> Unit) {
    Row {
        IconButton(onClick = { onEvent(ClearOutputItems) }) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Delete,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.uart_clear_items),
            )
        }
    }
}

private val datFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)

private fun UARTRecord.timeToString(): String {
    return datFormatter.format(timestamp)
}
```

this is my app's build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-android'
//    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/git-tag-version.gradle")

if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Release")){
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    namespace 'no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox'

    compileSdk android_api_version

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox"
        minSdk android_min_api_version
        targetSdk android_api_version
        versionCode getVersionCodeFromTags()
        versionName getVersionNameFromTags()

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../keystore')
            storePassword System.env.KEYSTORE_PSWD
            keyAlias System.env.KEYSTORE_ALIAS
            keyPassword System.env.KEYSTORE_KEY_PSWD
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
    hilt {
        enableExperimentalClasspathAggregation = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Hilt requires to implement every module in the main app module
    //https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2123
    implementation project(':profile_bps')
    implementation project(':profile_csc')
    implementation project(':profile_cgms')
    implementation project(':profile_gls')
    implementation project(':profile_hrs')
    implementation project(':profile_hts')
    implementation project(':profile_prx')
    implementation project(':profile_rscs')

    implementation project(':profile_uart')

    implementation project(":lib_analytics")
    implementation project(":lib_theme")
    implementation project(":lib_utils")
    implementation project(":lib_service")
    implementation project(":lib_log")

    implementation libs.nordic.theme
    implementation libs.nordic.ble.common
    implementation libs.nordic.ui.scanner
    implementation libs.nordic.navigation

    implementation libs.bundles.hilt
    kapt libs.bundles.hiltkapt

    implementation libs.bundles.icons
    implementation libs.bundles.compose
    implementation libs.androidx.core
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.lifecycle.activity
    implementation libs.compose.lifecycle
    implementation libs.compose.activity

    testImplementation libs.test.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.android.test.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.android.test.espresso
    androidTestImplementation libs.android.test.compose.ui
    debugImplementation libs.android.test.compose.tooling
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:7.1.3"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

and the module's build.gradle:

```
apply from: rootProject.file("library.gradle")
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0'
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":lib_analytics")
    implementation project(":lib_service")
    implementation project(":lib_theme")
    implementation project(":lib_utils")
    implementation project(":lib_log")

    implementation libs.room.runtime
    implementation libs.room.ktx
    kapt libs.room.compiler

    implementation libs.nordic.ble.common
    implementation libs.nordic.ble.ktx

    implementation libs.nordic.theme
    implementation libs.nordic.ui.scanner
    implementation libs.nordic.navigation

    implementation libs.bundles.datastore
    implementation libs.bundles.compose
    implementation libs.androidx.core
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.lifecycle.activity
    implementation libs.lifecycle.service
    implementation libs.compose.lifecycle
    implementation libs.compose.activity

    testImplementation libs.bundles.test

    implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.AAChartModel:AAChartCore-Kotlin:-SNAPSHOT'
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    namespace 'no.nordicsemi.android.uart'
}
```

and I uploaded the error into this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/N5ZyQhBF)(there is no specific error AFAIC)

Answer (score 2):

Use dependency with version :

```
implementation 'com.github.AAChartModel:AAChartCore-Kotlin:7.1.0'
```